xsdtojava compatiblity issues with java 17
My parent pom has spring boot version 3.3.2 and java 17, I am trying to migrate all javax to jakarta namespace.
If I downgrade my glassfish jaxb-runtime dependency to 2.x it works fine, but that dependency is not compatible with Java17 and I get different issues.
But below above pom.xml I get below error during xsdtojava step:
[ERROR] C:\Repositories\Java17\mso-core\mso\mso-api-handlers\mso-api-handler-att-services\target\null [-1:-1]: Failed to create model
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; Failed to create model
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:64)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.loadModel(XSDToJavaRunner.java:226)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.run(XSDToJavaRunner.java:174)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.main(XSDToJavaRunner.java:360)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.loadModel(XSDToJavaRunner.java:224)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.inheritance.Customizations.<clinit>(Customizations.java:31)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.inheritance.InheritancePlugin.getCustomizationElementNames(InheritancePlugin.java:50)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.AbstractPlugin.getCustomizationURIs(AbstractPlugin.java:97)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.<init>(AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.java:71)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.ExtensionBindingChecker.<init>(ExtensionBindingChecker.java:51)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$XMLSchemaParser.parse(ModelLoader.java:205)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:351)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.<init>(ParserContext.java:74)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.<init>(XSOMParser.java:83)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMParser(ModelLoader.java:378)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMSpeculative(ModelLoader.java:451)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:310)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:121)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:76)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:168)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:355)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:508)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:465)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.inheritance.Customizations.<clinit>(Customizations.java:28)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
        at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:165)
        ... 25 more


[ERROR] C:\Repositories\Java17\mso-core\mso\mso-api-handlers\mso-api-handler-att-services\src\main\resources\xsd\att\CanopiServiceRequestV1.xsd [0:0]: Failed to create model

My CanopiServiceRequestV1.xsd looks like this:
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://ecomp.att.com/mso/request/types/v1" 
    xmlns:msoservtypes="http://ecomp.att.com/mso/service/instance/types/v1" 
    targetNamespace="http://ecomp.att.com/mso/request/types/v1" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <import namespace="http://ecomp.att.com/mso/service/instance/types/v1" schemaLocation="MsoServiceInstanceTypesV1.xsd"/>
    
    <complexType name="vpnData">
        <sequence>
            <element name="lppVpnId" type="string"/>
            <element name="vpnService" type="string"/>
            <element name="vpnRt" type="string"/>
            <element name="vpnRegion" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    
    <complexType name="requestParameters">
        <sequence>
            <element name="serviceType" type="string"/>
            <element name="lppCustomerId" type="string"/>
            <element name="vpnData" type="ns1:vpnData"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    
    <element name="requestDetails">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="serviceInfo" type="msoservtypes:serviceInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="requestInfo" type="msoservtypes:requestInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="subscriberInfo" type="msoservtypes:subscriberInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="cloudConfiguration" type="msoservtypes:cloudConfiguration" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="requestParameters" type="ns1:requestParameters"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    <element name="serviceInstanceRequestReference" type="msoservtypes:serviceInstanceRequestReference"/>
    <element name="asyncRequestStatus" type="msoservtypes:asyncRequestStatus"/>
    <element name="requestError" type="msoservtypes:requestError"/>
</schema>

pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.att.ecomp.mso</groupId>
    <artifactId>mso-api-handlers</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>mso-api-handler-att-services</artifactId>
  <name>mso-api-handler-att-services</name>
  <description>ECOMP SO API Handler ATT Services</description>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <json4s-jackson-version>3.2.4</json4s-jackson-version>
    <json4s-core-version>3.0.0</json4s-core-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-jakarta</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
              <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
              <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
      <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.9.1-1</artifactId>
      <version>${json4s-jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
      <artifactId>json4s-core_2.9.2</artifactId>
      <version>${json4s-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-providers</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.2</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
      <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
      <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.onap.sdc.sdc-distribution-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>sdc-distribution-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.att.ecomp.mso</groupId>
      <artifactId>mso-api-handler-common-att-services</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.onap.so</groupId>
      <artifactId>mso-api-handler-infra</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <classifier>${originalClassifier}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
      <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.vorburger.mariaDB4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>mariaDB4j</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-jersey2</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.onap.so</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.wix</groupId>
      <artifactId>wix-embedded-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
      <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
      <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/AllTestsTestSuite.java</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>groovy</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>true</skip>
              <includes>
                <include>%regex[.*scripts.*]</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>suites</parallel>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin-jakarta</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <resourcePackages>
            <resourcePackage>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler</resourcePackage>
            <resourcePackage>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.service.system.am</resourcePackage>
            <resourcePackage>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.service.dequeue</resourcePackage>
            <resourcePackage>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.service.system</resourcePackage>
            <resourcePackage>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.service.system.ccd</resourcePackage>
            <resourcePackage>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.service.system.omx</resourcePackage>
          </resourcePackages>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.ATTServicesApiHandlerApplication</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated</sourceRoot>
          <extensions>
            <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-dv:4.0.1</extension>
          </extensions>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <xsdOptions>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/CanopiServiceRequestV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.anapapihandler.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/CanopiServiceRequestV2.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.anap.apihandler.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/MsoRequestV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.anapapihandler.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/QueryResponses.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.anapapihandler.beans.queryresponse</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/MsoRequestQueryResponseV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.anapapihandler.beans.query.requestresponse</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/Layer3ServiceActivateRequestV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.layer3.serviceactivate.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/GetLayer3ServiceDetailsRequest1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.layer3.details.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/ChangeLayer3ServiceActivateRequestV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.changelayer3activate.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/Layer3TestAndTurnUpV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.layer3.testandturnup.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/ChangeLayer3ServiceProvRequestV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.changelayer3service.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/DisconnectLayer3ServiceRequestV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.disconnectlayer3.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/VnfActivateRequestV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.vnfactivate.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/VnfDesignRequestV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.vnfdesign.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/att/VnfRemoveRequestV1.xsd</xsd>
                  <packagename>com.att.ecomp.mso.apihandler.vnfremove.beans</packagename>
                </xsdOption>
              </xsdOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>extract-docker-file</id>
            <configuration>
              <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start</id>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[4.0.1,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <execute />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <execute />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>

My maven dependency tree having jaxb2 dependency:-
+- com.att.ecomp.mso:att-common:jar:1.8.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.onap.so:common:jar:1.8.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.onap.aai.schema-service:aai-schema:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.onap.aai.schema-service:aai-annotations:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:jar:0.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:0.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.google.code.javaparser:javaparser:jar:1.0.11:compile


I've seen org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.inheritance.Customizations in the exception. Do you use any of org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics ? I don't see this one in your pom.xml ?

@LaurentSchoelens I don't see anything direct dependency but when I try mvn dependency:tree command, I can see below in the chart:-
- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:jar:0.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:0.11.1:compile

Could you share more so I can get which dependency is getting jaxb2-basics ? You should drop in with JAXB4 equivalent : org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins:4.0.8 (actual latest) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb/jaxb-plugins/4.0.8

@LaurentSchoelens I have added the dependency tree part in my original question where jaxb2-basics I found, so you mean to add org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins:4.0.8 to my pom right?

You can't move to jakarta because org.onap.aai.schema-service:aai-schema:jar:1.9.7 depends on jaxb-2.3 see pom here.
Moreover, they import the wrong runtime dependency (it should be jaxb2-basics-runtime and not jaxb2-basics itself which should only be used in the xsd -> java processing)
You can try asking the developer of the module to move to jakarta or propose a jakarta-based dependency so you can add as project dependency.
